# How can I make EntityFramework use a connectionstring from other files than app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dll

Can I make EntityFramework (6.1.1) look for a connectionstring in other files than app.config, and how can I accomplish that?

I'm developing a CustomAttributeStore.dll for Microsoft ADFS which is installed by copying the dll to C:\Windows\ADFS\ and restarting ADFS. I tried putting my connectionstring in CustomAttributeStore.dll.config, but I figured out that EF looks in Microsoft.IdentityServer.Servicehost.exe.config since my dll is loaded by ADFS. I don't want to place my connectionstring in Microsoft's config-file (even though it works..) How can I make EF look for a connectionstring in "custom.config"?

I'm calling my context-constructor specifying to use connectionstring:

```
var db = new MyContext("name=connectionstringname");
```

Comment: http://bit.ly/1pevqC0 It's just an idea - I'm not sure this would help you, so I haven't created answer for it.

Comment: Do you know you can pass your connection string to that constructor ? there is no automatic way for EF to lookp your custom config. You can parse your own config file and pass the connection string to Context's constructor

Comment: No I didn't know that, but I do now ;-) Simply passing the connectionstring in my Factory-class/context-constructor worked perfectly, thank you. ps. I couldn't mark your comment as answer.